# Add additional IPs to lo interface in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I need to setup aliases on the loopback(`lo`) interface in my docker container. I can't figure out how to do this in the docker-compose file.

I need to add 127.0.0.2, 127.0.0.3, and 127.0.0.4 to the `lo` interface. How can this be done in the docker-compose file?

On my mac I could just do something like `ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.4 up` but I can't figure out how to get this done in a docker container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, linux will respond to 127.0.0.2-4 by default as `127.0.0.1/8` is assigned to the `lo` interface. You may not need to "add" the addresses to the interface, just use them.

If for some reason you need the specific address on the interface, then it requires getting into the internals of Docker networking. There is a utility called [`pipework`](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework) that deals with this type of thing and these steps are lifted from it's code.

Get the PID of the container

```
NSPID=$(docker inspect -f '{{ .State.Pid }}' <container>)
```

Let `ip netns` work for this container

```
mkdir -p /var/run/netns
rm -f "/var/run/netns/$NSPID"
ln -s "/proc/$NSPID/ns/net" "/var/run/netns/$NSPID"
```

Add the IP address to the interface

```
ip netns exec $NSPID ip ad add 127.0.0.2/32 dev lo
```

Confirm the new config is there

```
ip netns exec $NSPID ip ad sh lo
```

This allows you to make any changes in the containers network namespace.